# How to restart tomcat on unexpected but graceful shutdown

Tags: windows, tomcat, service, shutdown

first some context: Tomcat 7.0.42 / AJP/1.3 / httpd-2.2.15 / java 1.7.0_49 @ Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 64bit

With our previous tomcat installation (tomcat 6 / java 6) we sometimes encountered JVM crashes. Because of that we configured the tomcat service to "restart on error" which worked ok.

Now with tomcat 7 sometimes the following error pops up (it is always the last entry in tomcat-err):

```
ClientAbortException:  java.io.IOException: Failed to send AJP message
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to send AJP message
```

which causes tomcat to shut down. This shutdown is apparently graceful, otherwise the "restart on error" setting would kick in, which it doesn't, so tomcat stays down :-(

Is there a way to maybe add a listener which "System.exit(-1)"s when tomcat is shutting down gracefully and unexpectedly for this specific cause?

Of course I'll try to track down the above error, but first I want to have means to keep tomcat up even when it unexcpectedly shuts down gracefully.

cheers,
alexander

Answer (score 0):

For problematic services, i usually use [the Non-Sucking Service Manager](http://nssm.cc/). Third party, open source, and incredibly configurable. While you find the error in your server, this can help.